# Filter all row with the same foreign key when a those column is null in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have table schema in mysql for my project.

this project build with laravel and as you can see in the below image i want to fillter all row with the same `store_id` when a row with the same `store_id` has a column with a custom value such as unactive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdX33.jpg)

in the select result i dont want to see a row with the `sotre_id = 2`.

because in mysql table i have row with `sotre_id = 2` that row have a column `active = 0`

please help me to get the wanted result in laravel query builder or mysql query

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where store_id in (select store_id from table where active = 0 )
```

eloquent:

```
Model::whereIn('store_id, Model::where('active', 0)->pluck('store_id))->get()
```